# How to use Eclipse 3.x views in E4?

Tags: java, eclipse, e4, eclipse-pde

I am experienced with Eclipse 3.x development and now want to develop an E4 application. Therefor I tested a simple example in order to get started with the new things.

I was following [this tutorial](http://atejedadev.com/post/eclipse3_views_in_eclipse4/) step by step but it results in the same error. However, he is not getting those errors.

I'm using Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) and installed the [E4 Tools (0.17)](http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/drops/S-0.17-201501051100/repository/). 
I've created a new Eclipse 4 Application and added to the `Application.e4xmi` the Common Resource Navigator (Project Explorer) as *Shared Part* using Import 3x -> View as CompatibilityView. I then added a *Placeholder* which references the shared part. I have added all necessary plugins to the product's dependencies. I also have added the compatibility plugins.

However, when I start the application I get an `InjectionException` at `InjectorImpl#internalMake()#331` which simply is:

```
if (unresolved(actualArgs) != -1) continue;
```

Debugging `unresolved()` let me to the following point (`InjectorImpl#489`):

```
Creatable creatableAnnotation = desiredClass.getAnnotation(Creatable.class);
```

Where  the `desiredClass` is class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference`.
Then the function returns 1 which leads to continue in the upper case and the exception. The stacktrace is the following ([full here](http://pastebin.ca/2998961)):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-05-06 13:00:05.899
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' from bundle '96'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Could not find satisfiable constructor in org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
...
```

Comment: This looks like the discussion [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/275906/) which is saying you can only use this by initializing all the 3.x compatibility mode. 3.x views require lots of things that are just not in a pure e4 application.

Comment: I did read this. The only answer from Eclipse staff (P. Webster) was *Yes, you need the entire 4.2 Workbench (plus all of its services) to instantiate a 3.x IViewPart correctly.* Well, I added a dependency to `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` and its dependencies. The people in the thread could not solve this and it was further left uncommented.

Comment: Yes but that does not initialize anything. As far as I know the only way to do that is using a traditional 3.x RCP

Comment: All tutorials I found where just doing what I did and it worked for them. The E4 tools I installed are built against the `Eclipse 4.3 SDK`. But there are no more recent ones. The [tutorial of Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#architecture_eclipsercp) (vogella) is outdated, too.

Comment: No, you **can** use Eclipse 3.x views in E4. That is actually done in the current Eclipse since JDT etc. are not ported to E4, yet.

Comment: The compatibility layer mentioned by Lars is initialized when you use a 3.x RCP, this has not changed in 4.4.

Comment: I was following [this tutorial](http://atejedadev.com/post/eclipse3_views_in_eclipse4/) step by step. And he is not getting those errors ... Tried it with the console ... same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to follow [this awesome tutorial](https://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/). As @greg-449 already mentioned you've to use an 3.x RCP and put an **e4 aware** product on top of it. Then the compatibility layer will be initialized. Thus, you have to do the following (the tutorial describes it in detail):

1. create an Ecliplse-Plugin which for *Eclipse 3.5 or newer*
2. Tick *Will make contributions to the UI*
3. Use the *Hello World* RCP to generate the required extension points
4. Ctrl+N -> Eclipse 4 -> Model -> New Application Model
5. Add an extension point
6. Ctrl+N -> Plug-in Development -> Product Configuration

The rest is described in the linked tutorial. Do **not** forget to add *-clearPersistedState* to the Launching options of the product. So you will see your deltas of your application model. If you are going to use a feature based product you should create a feature plugin which references your RCP plugin and add it as dependency to the product. Thus, you don't  have to change the run configuration as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

From what I have searched till today, you cannot use existing Eclipse UI plugins like `org.eclipse.debug.ui`, `org.eclipse.ui.console`, etc in a pure e4 application (`org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application`). So if you need to use existing UI components you have to create a 3.x application (implements `IApplication`, references `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor`, `PlatformUI` etc). So as of today if you want to use existing UI plugins you have to create a 3.x RCP which runs over the compatibility layer with the new 4.x runtime. This is so simple but hardly written clearly anywhere and I had to spend some time figuring it out. Discouraging introduction to Eclipse RCP.